# How do I change the image on a <asp:buttonField type="Image" /> in code behind?

Tags: asp.net

I have a `<asp:GridView >` with a `<asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Image">` as one of the columns.

Here's the problem: I have to dynamically change the image of this ButtonField during the `gridView_RowDataBound(...)` event based on the data found in that particular gridview row.

The real question is, is how to access that particular ButtonField inside the `gridView_RowDataBound(...)` event so I can change its image in C# code?

I can't use

```
Image imgCtrl = (Image)args.Row.FindControl("ctrlID");
```

because the `<asp:ButtonField>` won't allow an ID to be set (get a parser error when I try to run the webPage). And I can't use

```
args.Row.Cells[0].Controls[0];
```

because the zeroth index of the .Controls[0] doesn't exist (I get a boundry overflow error).

There's got to be a simple, slick, easy way to do this!

Comment: I would use custom templatecolumn which would give you full control.

Answer (score 2):

**Quick Example :**

```
    protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        DataRowView drv = (DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem; 
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            TableCell tableCell = e.Row.Cells[3]; // Column 3 in the grid have the Image Button 
            foreach (var control in tableCell.Controls)
            {
                if (control.GetType() == typeof(System.Web.UI.WebControls.ImageButton)) ;
                {
                    ImageButton iButton = control as ImageButton;
                    iButton.ImageUrl = "/Logo.jpg";
                }
            }
        }
    }
```